# Inkscape/SVG - can I define a color name local to an Inkscape SVG file?

Tags: svg, inkscape

Ok, simple description - is it possible to define variables in an Inkscape (or general) SVG?

I would like to be able to define something like `brand-color-primary` as a color (with a suitable default) and then be able to re-define it externally by finding something like `<color name="brand-color-primary" value="#xxyyzz">` and replacing the value.

Why? Because I could set colors like `brand-color-primary`, `brand-color-secondary`, `brand-color-border`, etc. If I define a transition from `brand-color-primary` to `brand-color-secondary` it will use the defined values for the colors. I could then generate a bunch of PNG files with different colors and automate selecting what looks good and what doesn't.

Basically I want to use this in a CI/CD environment with A/B testing to see what color combinations work best.

I can do this already by using 'well known values' for the things I want to change but this has problems - the 'well known values' may be used elsewhere by accident, using a name instead of a 'well known value' is a lot easier and requires less external documentation.

Is this possible? Can I define what is essentially a variable in InkScape SVG?

Comment: Ok, I realize I have capitalized Inkscape incorrectly - my bad.
Update: Edited question for correct capitilization.

Comment: Use css. You can set colors in css and uses classes.

Answer (score 0):

As Kevin remarked in his comment, svg accepts to be styled through css, so if it accepts css, why would not accept css variables too? The main notice here is that you must get all the inline styles, usually within every svg element, and place them inside `style` tags on de `defs` section of the svg code, or place them externally in a css file. to notice too that the election of one or the other method is deppendant of the goal you are pursuing.

Answer (score 0):

In Inkscape, there are two ways to do this:

- use custom swatches to create named colors
- use CSS styles to assign styles

Answer (score 0):

(This answer augments previous answers from users Moini and SIMBIOSIS)

Perhaps also use an SCSS preprocessor - in there you can define variables.

You can write for-loops in SCSS to, say, generate stepwise variations of styles, e.g., add increments of opacity.

Then style your SVG elements with CSS , by just exchanging 1 the `class=""` attribute.